# How to write a postback event in javascript for dropdownlist

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have two dropdownlists  ID and Name

If I select ID then Names under that ID should be displayed.

I tried it with using autopostback event,But i want to use it through AJAX or JAVAscript as per my requirement.

how to use pastbackevent with ajax or javascript

If i select ID 2 then Names Dropdown should be changed.I tried using script on selectchangeindex event but it not works

Comment: I think this case does not need post back. Because your `ID` and `Name` dropdownlist already contained all the data you need. What you should do is `Load` all data to `ID` and `Name` at `Page_Load`. Then at client side, use `JQUERY` or `Javascript` to sync selectedIndex of `ID` and `Name`

Comment: Can you provide your Code?

Answer (score 2):

In easy way , I suggest you to use `UpdatePanel` . For  Example ,
In aspx ,

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                <ContentTemplate>
                   <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropDownOne">
                   </asp:DropDownList>
                </ContentTemplate>
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="dropDownTwo" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
                </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>

  <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropDownTwo" AutoPostBack="true"    
  OnSelectedIndexChanged="Two_SelectedIndexChanged" ></asp:DropDownList>
```

In cs ,

```
    protected void Two_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectedIndexChangedEventArgs e)
    {
           //......Rebind dropDownOne's datasource here !.....
    }
```

In my example , `dropDownTwo` will be your `ID_dropdownList` and `dropDownOne` will be your `Name_DropDownList` . Good Luck !